# Test whether the values in a row in two columns exist in any row in two other columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have 5 columns where I need to check whether the values of A and B of a row are found in the same sequence on any row in C and D, then output the result in E.  The result will be true or false for whether the A&B content of that row has a C&D match on any row:

```
╔════════╦═════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║   A    ║    B    ║   C    ║    D    ║   E   ║
╠════════╬═════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ red    ║ donkey  ║ black  ║ chicken ║ FALSE ║
║ black  ║ chicken ║ yellow ║ donkey  ║ TRUE  ║  <===
║ yellow ║ fish    ║ red    ║ fish    ║ FALSE ║
╚════════╩═════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

As you can see: black/chicken is the only true value as it exists in a row in C/D.

Comment: "they should be in the same row" - `black / chicken` isn't appearing in the same row in both columns in your example. what do you refer by "same row"? Please try to clarify your description.

Comment: I mean C and D should be in the same row

Comment: So if A was black, and B was chicken, and C was chicken and D was black, would that be a match? Otherwise, you're simply saing if A + row = C (remember row) and B + row =D (get the remembered row) then it's a match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. `SUMPRODUCT` function for this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1=C:C)*(B1=D:D))>0`

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up for readers: the question has a LO Calc tag.  Older versions of LO Calc couldn't handle whole column addressing (e.g., C:C).  IIRC, it was added sometime around V5.  If you have an old version and the formula doesn't work, upgrade to the current version of LO.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the order is important. (black chicken shouldn't match with chicken black). In this case, you could make 2 new columns with combined data of AB and CD.
[formula would be :  `=A1&B1` , just separate the cells with an "&".]

Thus, your table would look like

```
    E          F
reddonkey      blackchicken
blackchicken   yellowdonkey
```

and so forth. Then you use the formula

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH([cell column F],[entire column E],TRUE)`

The formula just checks if there is a match for a particular cell in a given list.

Comment: This is a good solution but the answer would be better if you gave an actual example (working formula).  The descriptive formula is helpful as supplementary explanation for how it works.